# Initialize delegate from class file

Tags: ios, swift, function, delegates

I am building an app using swift. I am trying to pass information and trigger a function from the class file of a custom AnnotationClusterView to a ViewController. To do this I'm implementing a delegate. But I don't know where and how to initialize it. Here is the custom AnnotationClusterView class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

protocol MyDelegate {
    func thatGuy(guy: Int)
}

class FBAnnotationClusterView : MKAnnotationView {
    var delegate: MyDelegate!
    var countLabel:UILabel? = nil


    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let cluster:FBAnnotationCluster = annotation as! FBAnnotationCluster

        for annot in cluster.annotations {
            let fbannot: FBAnnotation = (annot as? FBAnnotation)!
            imageArray.append(fbannot.image)
        }
        setupButtons()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setupButtons() {
        var xFactor = 1
        for butt in self.imageArray {
            let yFactor = CGFloat(xFactor * 40)
            let buttButt: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(yFactor, 80, 16, 16))
            buttButt.setImage(butt, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            buttButt.tag = xFactor
            buttButt.addTarget(self, action: "thumbButt:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            addSubview(buttButt)
            xFactor++
        }
    }


    func thumbButt(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button Pressed")
        self.delegate?.thatGuy(sender.tag)
    }

}
```

Here is the ViewController code:

```
    import MapKit
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, MyDelegate {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
          ...
       }

       func thatGuy(guy: Int) {
           print("thatGuy func reached!")
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in viewDidLoad:

```
var annotationView = FBAnnotationClusterView(...
annotationView.delegate = self;
```

That should do the job.

But I think you should create the annotation in

```
  viewForAnnotation
```

method of the `MapView` protocol and that the place where the view should be created and delegate seated.